# Unbox an Object to Its Type

Tags: c#

is there anyway to unbox an object to its real type?

Basically I am given an `ArrayList`, the array list are actually a list of `int` or `double`, or maybe other types ( it can be either, but it is either all `int` or `double`, no mix). Now, I will have to return a `List<double>` or `List<int>` or other list, depending on what is the real type.

```
public List<T> ConvertToList<T>(ArrayList arr)
{
    var list1 = new List<T>();
    foreach(var obj in arr)
   {
     // how to do the conversion?
     var objT = ??
     list1.Add(objT);
    }
    return list1;
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using .NET 3.5, there's a much easier way to do this:

```
public List<T> ConvertToList<T>(IEnumerable original)
{
    return original.Cast<T>().ToList();
}
```

(I've generalised the parameter to just `IEnumerable` as we're not using anything specific to `ArrayList` here.)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Convert class.

```
var objT = (T)Convert.ChangeType(obj, typeof(T));
```

Comment: Erhm, that returns object, which is what you have in the first place. You are doing a convertion 2 times. `(T)obj;` would be enough.

Comment: @Filip you are right. But this solution is a bit more tolerant. That way it's also possible to convert string to int if the Convert doesn't fail.

Comment: But that's not the question that was asked. Personally, if I expected an ArrayList to only contain boxed values I'd rather get an exception if it started to contain strings or indeed boxed values of unexpected types. Only the casting to T bit is actually relevant to the question as asked.

Comment: @Jon he said "..or maybe other types" :-) that's why I choose this solution.

Comment: But if the point in each case is just to do an unboxing conversion rather than the rather larger range of conversions provided by `Convert.ChangeType` then I think just casting to `T` is more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

You can just regular Type Cast like this

```
public List<T> ConvertToList<T>(ArrayList arr)
{
    var list1 = new List<T>();
    foreach(var obj in arr)
   { 
     // Like this 
     list1.Add((T)obj);

    }
    return list1;
}
```

Comment: That will not compile; the `as` operator is valid only for reference types.